# WordPress - WP_Widget : Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function WP_Widget::__construct()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget

Im new to custom wordpress widget creation and im trying to create one. I created my widget at `wp-content> plugins> custom-widgets> my-custom-widget.php`.

This is my code

```
if(!class_exists("MyCustomWidget")){
    
    class MyCustomWidget extends WP_Widget{
       
        public function __constructor(){
            parent::WP_Widget(false,"My custom Widget");
        }
      
        public function form($instance){
            ?>
            <p>

            <label>Tilte:</label>
            <input type="text"/>
            
            </p>
            <?php

        }
    }
    
    function register_my_widget(){
        register_widget("MyCustomWidget");
    }
    
    add_action("widgets_init", "register_my_widget");
}
```

When im trying to activate it i get the wordpress fail page and specially the following. What is wrong?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function WP_Widget::__construct(), 0 
passed in F:\Downloads\Worpress\Wordpress Local\apache2\htdocs\store\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-
widget-factory.php on line 61 and at least 2 expected in F:\Downloads\Worpress\Wordpress 
Local\apache2\htdocs\store\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-widget.php:162 Stack trace: #0 
F:\Downloads\Worpress\Wordpress Local\apache2\htdocs\store\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-widget-
factory.php(61): WP_Widget->__construct() #1 F:\Downloads\Worpress\Wordpress 
Local\apache2\htdocs\store\wordpress\wp-includes\widgets.php(115): WP_Widget_Factory->register() #2 
F:\Downloads\Worpress\Wordpress Local\apache2\htdocs\store\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\custom-widget\wp-
custom-widget.php(34): register_widget() #3 F:\Downloads\Worpress\Wordpress 
Local\apache2\htdocs\store\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(287): register_my_widget() #4 
F:\Downloads\Worpress\Wordpress Local\apache2\htdocs\store\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(311): 
WP in F:\Downloads\Worpress\Wordpress Local\apache2\htdocs\store\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-
widget.php on line 162
```

Answer (score 3):

See [this answer from wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/383778/58791) for a full correct widget example.

There is a couple of issues with the code in this question:

1. It's `function __construct()` and not `function __constructor()`.
2. As detailed in rich's answer the parent call should be to `parent::__construct(..)`. For example: `parent::__construct('', 'Widget name');`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the OP's problem when updated an old WordPress site from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.1 .

For me, the solution was to go into Appearance > Widgets, making a minor change to the content in each widget area and re-saving.

Before I did that, I made sure all my themes and plugins were up-to-date.

The site now runs fine on PHP 8.1

Answer (score -2):

In your constructor, you need to pass 2 arguments... so something like this:

```
public function __constructor(){
    parent::__construct('my_custom_widget',v__('My Custom Widget', 'my_text_domain'));
}
```

WordPress documentation here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget/__construct/